# Reforming the Roman Empire as Catholic

Tags: crusader-kings-2

Is it possible? I get the impression that you have to be orthodoxy to form the Roman Empire, but I'm not 100% sure. If you don't convert to orthodoxy, what would be your path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible as a Catholic.

Aside from the land requirements the only other requirements are being Christian (which could include Catholicism or even one of its heresies), being the Byzantine Emperor, and 3000 prestige (which you would easily end up with anyway).